# How to add bash auto completion to `k3s kubectl ...`?

Tags: kubectl, k3s, bash-completion

I add bash-completion for k3s by running:

```
. <( k3s completion bash )
```

When I run the following, I only get bash-completion for `kubectl ...` and not `k3s kubectl ...`:

```
. <( k3s kubectl completion bash )
```

However `k3s kubectl`<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't complete the `kubectl` context.

What I ended up doing for now, is having a function (see blow) that runs `k3s kubectl` when I call `kubectl` but I would still like the `proper` way to work as well.

```
kubectl() {
    k3s kubectl "${@}"
}
```

Is there a way to add bash auto completion to `k3s kubectl ...` ?